# Convert bytea with multiple octals to an integer

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get a value out of a Postgres DB that is stored as a bytea.
The values are VLAN ID's (so integers between 1-4096).

However, it's stored in the db (as an example) as:

```
\000\000\001\221 (equal to 401)
```

I'd like to have my SQL query return the integer value if possible to my python code.

After some searching, I can use get_byte to get one of those 4 octals (by specifying the position):

```
select get_byte(sub.datavlan_bytes,3) AS vlan -> this gives me the value of /221 (145)
```

However, I can't get the entire value.

Is there a good way to get the data in a select query, or does that need to happen in my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain SQL by casting:

```
select ('x' || encode(o, 'hex'))::bit(32)::int
from (values ('\000\000\001\221'::bytea)) s (o)
;
 int4 
------
  401
```

Comment: Yes, plpgsql unnecessary, just cast.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres 9+ offers a `hex` format for `bytea` values. If you can set the `bytea_output` connection setting to `hex` (which is the default, so it probably already is...) you can get back a string that can be fed to Python's `int(..., 16)` function. That would get your 401 directly.

**Edit:** Postgres docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-binary.html